# How to handle 400 bad request with response in ionic 2 / angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have an ionic 2 app with a login page. In my login page I have a function (`doLogin()`) that is hit when the user clicks on the login button.

When I provide the correct username and password, I get a response and I can store the access_token in my storage. The problem is, that when I enter wrong credentials, the server returns a 400 error, with a json respons:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "The user name or password is incorrect."
}
```

How can I capture the error_description so that I can display that to the user?

The function in my login page looks like this:

```
doLogin(){
    this.authService.getAccessToken(this.userName, this.password, response => {
    console.log("My response: " + response);
      if(response.access_token != null) {
        this.storage.set('access_token', response.access_token).then(() => {
          console.log('Token is set');
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        });
      }
      else {
        alert("To bad for you");
      }
   });
}
```

The service that is called is this:

```
getAccessToken(usr:string, pwd:string, callback){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    var data = "grant_type=password" 
                + "&username=" + usr
                + "&password=" + pwd

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

    this.http.post(authTokenUrl, data, options)
        .map(response => response.json())

        .subscribe(
            (response) => callback(response),
            (err) => callback(err.status)
        ),error => {
            console.log("Oooops!");
        }, () => {
            console.log("To Bad");
    };
}
```

Comment: Don't subscribe from the service. return the observable, and subscribe from the component, with a success callback saving the token, and an error callback handling the error.